# Dados do Request estão vindo nulos

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, laravel

**Contextualização** 

Ao excluir um registro do histórico de erratas ocorre o **erro 404** que o objeto não foi encontrado; o objeto está vindo vazio. Como solucionar este problema?

A requisição está chegando no **controller**.
Mas não é encontrado uma errata com aquele id e o Controller devolve 404.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Método removeErrata da classe ProjetoController.php**

```
   //Este método remove a  Errata 
         public function removeErrata(Request $request)
         {
             $errata = HistoricoErrata::where('id_historico_errata', $request->id)->get()->first();


             if (!$errata)
             return response()
                         ->json(['error' => 'not_found'], 404);

             $response = $errata->delete();  

             if($response)
             {
             return response()
                     ->json(['success' => 'Sucesso ao Remover a Errata'], 200);  

             }else
             {
                 // Caso não delete, informa um erro inesperado
             return response()
                         ->json(['error' => 'Erro ao Remover a Errata'], 500);        
             } 
         }
```

**Arquivo em Ajax para remover a errata**

```
 $(document).on('click', '#btnExcluirErrata', function () {
      $('#idErrata').val($(this).data('id'));
      $('#dataErrata').text($(this).data('dterrata'));
    });

    //Ajax para remover uma errata, e atualizar a página após a ação
    $('.removeErrata').click(function () {
      var data_id = $('#idErrata').data('id');


      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
      }); 

      $.ajax({
          url:  "/projetos/removeErrata",
          type: "POST",
          data: {id: data_id},
          dataType: "json"
      }).done(function (response) {

        console.log(response);
          if (response.success) {  

               alert("Sucesso ao excluir a errata");

            setTimeout(function(){
                    location.reload();
                }, 2000); 
          }
          else {
             alert(response.error);

          }   
      }).fail(function () {
             alert ('Sucesso ao Excluir a Errata');
      });

      return false;
    });


    //Evento que preencherá o modal View de histórico Erratas
    $(document).on('click', '.btnViewErrata',function () {
      $('#modalViewIdErrata').val(($(this).data('id')));
      $('#modalViewDtErrata').val(($(this).data('dterrata')));
      $('#modalViewAltPublicada').val(($(this).data('altpublicada')));
    });

    //Evento que preencherá o modal  Editar de histórico Erratas
    $(document).on('click', '.btnEditErrata',function () {
      $('#modalEditIdErrata').val(($(this).data('id')));
      $('#modalEditDtErrata').val(($(this).data('dterrata')));
      $('#modalEditAltPublicada').val(($(this).data('altpublicada')));
    });
```

**Modal de Remover Errata da página edita.blade.php**

```
 <!-- Inicio do Modal de Excluir Erratas-->
             <div class="modal fade modal-danger" id="modalExcluirErrata" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="examplePositionCenter"
                 role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-center">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Exclusão da Errata</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <input type="hidden" id="idErrata">
                            <p>Deseja excluir a errata da data  "<span id="dataErrata"></span>"?</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger removeErrata" data-dismiss="modal">Excluir</a>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-pure" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Fim do Modal de Excluir Erratas -->
```

**Erros** 

Erro 1

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro 2

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Rotas**

Web.php

```
//Gerenciar Projetos

    $this->group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'namespace' =>'admin','prefix'=>'projetos'], function(){
        //Inicio das Rotas de gerenciar projetos
        $this->post('cadastro','ProjetoController@cadastro')->name('projeto.cadastro');
        $this->post('cadastroAprovacao','ProjetoController@cadastroAprovacao')->name('projeto.cadastroAprovacao');
        $this->post('cadastroJuridico','ProjetoController@cadastroJuridico')->name('projeto.cadastroJuridico');
        $this->post('cadastroContratosConvenios','ProjetoController@cadastroContratosConvenios')->name('projeto.cadastroContratosConvenios');
        $this->post('cadastroFinanceiro','ProjetoController@cadastroFinanceiro')->name('projeto.cadastroFinanceiro');
        $this->post('projeto','ProjetoController@consulta')->name('projeto.consulta');
        $this->post('atualiza', 'ProjetoController@atualiza')->name('projeto.atualiza');
        $this->post('remove','ProjetoController@remove')->name('projeto.remove');
        $this->get('edita/{id}','ProjetoController@edita')->name('projeto.edita');
        $this->get('novo','ProjetoController@novo')->name('projeto.novo');
        $this->get('projeto','ProjetoController@index')->name('admin.projeto');
        $this->post('autorizaDocumentacao','ProjetoController@autorizaDocumentacao')->name('projeto.autorizaDocumentacao');
        $this->post('autorizaProjeto','ProjetoController@autorizaProjeto')->name('projeto.autorizaProjeto');
        $this->post('autorizaPagamento','ProjetoController@autorizaPagamento')->name('projeto.autorizaPagamento');
        $this->get('localidadesAtivas','ProjetoController@localidadesAtivas')->name('projeto.localidadesAtivas');

        $this->post('editaErrata','ProjetoController@editaErrata')->name('projeto.editaErrata');
        $this->post('editaNotificacao','ProjetoController@editaNotificacao')->name('projeto.editaNotificacao');
        $this->post('removeNotificacao','ProjetoController@removeNotificacao')->name('projeto.removeNotificacao');
        $this->post('removeErrata','ProjetoController@removeErrata')->name('projeto.removeErrata');
        $this->post('cadastroNotificacao','ProjetoController@cadastroNotificacao')->name('projeto.cadastroNotificacao');
        $this->post('cadastroErrata','ProjetoController@cadastroErrata')->name('projeto.cadastroErrata');
       //Final das Rotas de gerenciar projetos
    });
```

Comment: Ruama, coloque também o código do seu arquivo de rotas e veja na aba "Response" do dev. tools (ultimo print que voce postou)

Comment: RFL, o código das rotas e o print da aba response foi postado como recomendado.

Comment: Obrigada pelo feedback :)

Comment: De qualquer modo, isso não seria uma discussão para termos aqui, mas sugiro fortemente - caso ainda não o tenha feito - dar uma revisada no [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), procurar postar código como texto ao invés de imagem e sempre que possível disponibilizar um [mcve]. =) bem vinda (tardiamente)